# Two sum algorithm with bsearch (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

I just started learning Ruby not too long ago and was confused with this two-sum algorithm. Basically, the algorithm will return true if there are any two integers in the array that add up to the sum, and false if not. I am familiar with the bsearch method in Ruby, but can't figure out why there is:

```
match_idx && match_idx != i
```

Shouldn't it just be:

```
match_idx != i
```

Code in question:

```
def okay_two_sum_b(arr, target)
    arr = arr.sort
    arr.each_with_index do |el, i|
        match_idx = arr.bsearch_index { |el2| (target - el) <=> el2 }
        return true if match_idx && match_idx != i
    end
    false
end



arr = [0, 1, 5, 7]
p bad_sum(arr, 6) # => should be true
p bad_sum(arr, 10) # => should be false
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given value of `el`, `match_idx` will equal a non-negative integer (an index of `arr`) if there is an index `el2` of `arr` such that `arr[el] + arr[el2] == target`, else `match_idx` will equal `nil`, so you have to make sure `match_id` is not `nil` before checking `match_idx != i`.

Let's see if we can make the method more efficient, considering that the time complexity of sorting is O(nlog(n)), where n is the size of the array.

```
require 'set'
```

```
def two_sum?(arr, target)
  return true if target.even? && (arr.count(target/2) > 1)
  st = arr.to_set
  st.each do |e|
    f = target-e
    return true if e != f && st.include?(f)
  end
  false 
end
```

```
two_sum?([0, 1, 5, 7], 6)   #=> true
```

```
two_sum?([0, 1, 5, 7], 10)  #=> false
```

If n is the size of `arr`, the time complexity to construct the set (effectively the same as that of constructing an underlying hash) is O(n) and the time complexity of determining if the set contains a given value is only slightly worse than O(n).

Comment: I think even a "two pointers" implementation (O(nlog(n) + n))  should be faster than bsearch-based (O(2nlog(n)). Bsearch is a surprisingly bad fit here :)

Comment: If we're talking about raw efficiency, I'm not sure that special case in your implementation is warranted. It's an O(n) pass that will be a pure waste in most cases.

Comment: Thank you Cary! For some reason I was interpreting it as (match_idx && match_idx) != i and not match_idx && (match_idx != i). That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much.